# How to programmatically get latest offset per Kafka topic partition in Python

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-topic

I'm new to Kafka, and want to get the position of a Kafka topic, per partition.
I see in the documentation - https://kafka-[python.readthedocs.io/en/master/apidoc/KafkaAdminClient.html#kafkaadminclient](http://ducomentation) - that the offset is available via the function `KafkaAdminClient.list_consumer_group_offsets`, 
but I don't see such a method for the position there.

Does anybody know how I can get it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Using [`confluent-kafka-python`](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-python/)**

You can use [`position`](https://docs.confluent.io/current/clients/confluent-kafka-python/index.html#confluent_kafka.Consumer.position):

> Retrieve current positions (offsets) for the list of partitions.

```
from confluent_kafka import Consumer, TopicPartition


consumer = Consumer({"bootstrap.servers": "localhost:9092"})
topic = consumer.list_topics(topic='topicName')
partitions = [TopicPartition('topicName', partition) for partition in list(topic.topics['topicName'].partitions.keys())] 

offset_per_partition = consumer.position(partitions)
```

Alternatively, you can also use [`get_watermark_offsets`](https://docs.confluent.io/current/clients/confluent-kafka-python/index.html#confluent_kafka.Consumer.get_watermark_offsets) but you'd have to pass one partition at a time and thus it requires multiple calls:

> Retrieve low and high offsets for partition.

```
from confluent_kafka import Consumer, TopicPartition


consumer = Consumer({"bootstrap.servers": "localhost:9092"})
topic = consumer.list_topics(topic='topicName')
partitions = [TopicPartition('topicName', partition) for partition in list(topic.topics['topicName'].partitions.keys())] 

for p in partitions:
    low_offset, high_offset = consumer.get_watermark_offsets(p)
    print(f"Latest offset for partition {f}: {high_offset}")
```

---

**Using [`kafka-python`](https://github.com/dpkp/kafka-python)**

You can use [`end_offsets`](https://kafka-python.readthedocs.io/en/master/apidoc/KafkaConsumer.html#kafka.KafkaConsumer.end_offsets):

> Get the last offset for the given partitions. The last offset of a
>   partition is the offset of the upcoming message, i.e. the offset of
>   the last available message + 1.
>
> This method does not change the current consumer position of the
>   partitions.

```
from kafka import TopicPartition
from kafka.consumer import KafkaConsumer


consumer = KafkaConsumer(bootstrap_servers = "localhost:9092" )
partitions= = [TopicPartition('myTopic', p) for p in consumer.partitions_for_topic('myTopic')]
last_offset_per_partition = consumer.end_offsets(partitions)
```

If you want to iterate through all topics, the following will do the trick:

```
from kafka import TopicPartition
from kafka.consumer import KafkaConsumer


kafka_topics = consumer.topics()
for topic in kafka_topics: 
    partitions= = [TopicPartition(topic, p) for p in consumer.partitions_for_topic(topic)]
    last_offset_per_partition = consumer.end_offsets(partitions)
```

Comment: do I need to know the topic's list for it (for the 3rd solution)? by the command `topics()`?

Comment: @Chedva Which library are you using?

Comment: I'm using kafka library (kafka-python)

Comment: @Chedva No you don't. All you need is the topic name. Have you tried running the code?

Comment: not yet, but the thing is that I don't know the topic name beforehand, and I need it for all the topics that I have in the cluster

Comment: you helped a lot. tnx!

Comment: Does the consumer actually get assigned to the partitions ?..I'm trying to see if we can compute lag without explicit consumer assignment or subscription - similar to `kafka-consumer-groups.sh --group {group_id} --describe` operation.